# PERL-Subsitute any non alphanumerical character to "_"

Tags: regex, perl

In perl I want to substitute any character not `[A-Z]i` or `[0-9]` and replace it with "_" but only if this non alphanumerical character occurs between two alphanumerical characters.  I do not want to touch non-alphanumericals at the beginning or end of the string.

I know enough regex to replace them, just not to only replace ones in the middle of the string.

Comment: Sorry guys, I made a mistake.  I thought the file was using \n as the newline but it was using \r only.  Perl just cannot seem to handle \r and treats the whole file as one string.  That was the issue with it "eating" the \n.  All my fault sorry.

Comment: So this is how I ended up resolving it.  I know there are better ways, but I understand want it going on here: $lines =~ s/(\.|\?|\-| )/_/g; $lines =~ s/_{2,}/_/g; $lines =~ s/_{2,}$//; I tried to do the code tags but the four spaces didn't work, now I am confused.  I only used . - ? because they are the most common non alphanumerical symbol that comes up in the title in my fasta files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s/(\p{Alnum})\P{Alnum}(\p{Alnum})/${1}_${2}/g;
```

Of course that would hurt your chanches with "#A#B%C", so you might use a look-arounds:

```
s/(?<=\p{Alnum})\P{Alnum}(?=\p{Alnum})/_/g;
```

That way you isolate it to just the non "alnum" character.

Or you could use the "keep flag", as well and get the same thing done.

```
s/\p{Alnum}\K\P{Alnum}(?=\p{Alnum})/_/g;
```

---

***EDIT*** based on input:

To not eat a newline, you could do the following:

```
s/\p{Alnum}\K[^\p{Alnum}\n](?=\p{Alnum})/_/g;
```

Comment: So none of those worked.  Left a "." in there, and added a _ at the end of the string.  I should have also mentioned there has to be a line break at the end of that string and for some reason that command, though I don't understand how, ate the line break. Thanks

Comment: @user520742 All three should have worked, what is your input?

Comment: A fasta file style text document.  Basically it looks like this ">TITLE of any length or anything until \n  then DNA or AA sequence.  Here is the first bit of the file (I added \n for the linebreak), "B._bicolor_var._borealis Finished \n
CCKGGTCATCGKGATTTTATCAAAAACATGATCACCGGTACCTCCCAGGC
TGACTGCGCCATCCTCATTATCGCCGGTGGTACCGGTGAGTTCGAGGCTG"  Here is the output using your last example, "B._bicolor_var._borealis_Finished_CCKGGTCATCGKGATTTTATCAAAAACATGATCACCGGTACCTCCCAGGC_TGACTGCGCCATCCTCATTATCGCCGGTGGTACCGGTGAGTTCGAGGCTG_GTATCTCCAA"  Because it ate the line break it also inserts new "_"

Comment: Okay, that is a little messy sorry.  Since it eats the line break it also inserts more "_" where some line breaks are that would be removed by another part of the program.

Comment: @Axeman edit still ate the new line at the end, and replace the \s between the last letter and the \n with "_".  Could you also explain this to me, I would really like to know more than copy this and paste, it works.

Comment: Just tested Axeman's last solution and it works now that I am not stupid about the \r|\n thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my $str = 'a-2=c+a()_';
$str =~ s/(?<=[A-Z0-9])[^A-Z0-9](?=[A-Z0-9])/\1_\2/gi;
```

Comment: Did the same as above missed the ".", ate the line break, and added a "_" at the end of the string as there is white space there.

Comment: ok, You mean it is unable to detect "." as a non-alphanumeric? Can we chomp the newlines?

Comment: Yes, it was unable to detect "." and no I need that line break for the proper file format.

Comment: Based on sample data you provided above, It shouldn't be replacing '.' with '_'. The dots are not placed in between alphnumeric characters. Also I don't see how the newlines are getting replaced. Perhaps I am missing something here, some more details would be great.

Comment: Hmm.  Good point I had not thought about that.  Well I redid it and it does catch the "." if I put another letter around it.  Thanks.  However, the other two issues are still there.  Which newlines are you referencing?

Comment: more details.  the program takes a file that is in near fasta format and remove all unnecessary white space and new lines.  If you copy pasta a fasta file from the net you often have a bunch of newline symbols in the sequence area.  The program I wrote strips all those new lines and puts one at the end of the sequence.  I just wanted to make it where it would also replace any non alphanum character in the title of the seunce with _ as well since most bio programs (RAxML) does not like the spaces, however I dont want to add extre _ at the end of the title where spaces are fine.

Comment: You could try appending the newline after applying the regex and retain the current stripping of all newlines, and also avoid extra _ at the end. So the flow might be 1. strip all newlines 2. apply the regex, and 3. add extra newline at the end.

Comment: \1 and \2 are regular expression escapes. They have no business outside of the regular expression (which is why you get a warning). `s/.../\1_\2/gi` should be `s/.../${1}_$2/gi`

Comment: @ikegami, that explains the warnings I got.   @erickb-really seems like there should be a better solution than stripping and reapplying the newline.  Why is \n being called a alphanumeric character anyway?

Comment: \n is being called non-alphanumeric (`[^A-Z0-9]`), and thus replaced.

Comment: What warnings have you encountered? Not all lines/statements in fasax will encounter a captured match, You will get undefined warnings for those, if you want you can use `defined` function to check for presence of $1 and $2. It is not necessarily an escapes issue. Include `\n` in your group matches if you don't want to treat them as non-alphanumeric, @Axeman has provided a solution for this in his answer.

Comment: See above, the newline thing was my mistake.